# How to extract the last value in the last timestamp of a day?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has multiple values in a day. I want to extract the value which is from the last timestamp in a day.

```
Date_Timestamp         Values
2010-01-01 11:00:00    2.5
2010-01-01 15:00:00    7.1
2010-01-01 23:59:00    11.1
2010-02-01 08:00:00    12.5
2010-02-01 17:00:00    37.1
2010-02-01 23:53:00    71.1
```

output:

```
Date_Timestamp         Values
2010-01-01 23:59:00    11.1
2010-02-01 23:53:00    71.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html)
- This is a vectorized method, that is incredibly fast, compared to [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

```py
# given dataframe df with Date_Timestamp as a datetime
dfg = df.groupby(df.Date_Timestamp.dt.date).last().reset_index(drop=True)

# display(dfg)
     Date_Timestamp  Values
2010-01-01 23:59:00    11.1
2010-02-01 23:53:00    71.1
```

### `timeit` test

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# test data with 2M rows
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 2000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.bdate_range(datetime(2020, 1, 1), freq='h', periods=rows).tolist(),
                   'values': np.random.rand(rows, )*1000})

# display(df.head())

           datetime      values
2020-01-01 00:00:00  941.455743
2020-01-01 01:00:00  641.602705
2020-01-01 02:00:00  684.610467
2020-01-01 03:00:00  588.562066
2020-01-01 04:00:00  543.887219
```

```py
%%timeit
df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.date).last().reset_index(drop=True)
[out]:
100k: 39.8 ms ± 1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
200k: 80.7 ms ± 438 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
400k: 164 ms ± 659 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2M: 791 ms ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
# This answer, with apply, is terrible
# I let it run for 1.5 hours and it didn't finish
# I reran the test for this is 100k and 200k
%%timeit
df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.date)['values'].apply(lambda x: x.tail(1))
[out]:
100k: 2.42 s ± 23.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
200k: 8.77 s ± 328 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
400k: 38.2 s  # I only did %%time instead of %%timeit - it takes to long
800k: 2min 54s
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df['Date_Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Timestamp'])
df.groupby(df['Date_Timestamp'].dt.date)['Values'].apply(lambda x: x.tail(1))
```